# How to show file and folder names along with terminal icons without showing current directory?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, windows-terminal

I want to **remove the space/ area** taken up in showing the

```
Directory: C:\Users\varun\Desktop\Projects\advanced-react-patterns-v2
```

when I run the command:

```
Get-ChildItem | Format-Wide
```

[image: screenshot]]

Additional details:

- Using Windows Terminal & Powershell
- Font used in the screenshot: TerminessTTF NF
- Used [Terminal-Icons](https://github.com/devblackops/Terminal-Icons)

**Note**: The command

```
Get-ChildItem -Name
```

failed to show the terminal icons which kind of my main goal here.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using a `Format-*` command you are using the default formatting output for the File and Directory objects, which groups files by directory - hence the directory name at the top.

If you wanted to by pass this, you would have to write your own [format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7) file and then add the formatting to your output.

```bsh
$files = Get-ChildItem
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $file.PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0,'Custom.Output.Type')
    $file
}
```

Small sample of XML for the specified Typename, customise as you wish.

```xml
<View>
    <Name>CustomFileFormatting</Name>
    <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>Custom.Output.Type</TypeName>
    </ViewSelectedBy>
    <TableControl>
        <AutoSize />
        <TableHeaders>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Label>FullName</Label>
                <Alignment>Left</Alignment>
            </TableColumnHeader>
        </TableHeaders>
        <TableRowEntries>
            <TableRowEntry>
                <TableColumnItems>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>FSObject</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                </TableColumnItems>
            </TableRowEntry>
        </TableRowEntries>
    </TableControl>
</View>
```

Comment: Tried to create fromat.ps1xml, received the following error: 'c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\format.ps1xml' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\format.ps1xml')

Comment: I would create it in a user directory where your script is. Please follow the information in the link I provided on how to use the formatting data.

Comment: I have created /Mygciview.Format.ps1xml as specified in the link and put it in my project folder.

Comment: Then I made a custom power shell function as follow: function Format-TC {
    $files = Get-ChildItem
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $file.PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0,'Mygciview.Format.ps1xml')
    # $file
}}

Comment: You do not use the name of the XML in the insert statement, you use the TypeName. Please follow the linked documentation. It does work.